# Envoy retry_policy is not working even though the request is routed correctly

Tags: http, kubernetes, envoyproxy, cilium

I am using following envoy config:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener_0
      address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 8080
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: local_service
                      domains: [ "*" ]
                      routes:
                        - match:
                            prefix: "/"
                          route:
                            cluster: backend_service
                            retry_policy:
                              retry_on: 5xx
                              num_retries: 3
                              per_try_timeout: 10s
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
  clusters:
    - name: backend_service
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: STRICT_DNS
      lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: backend_service
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: service-front
                      port_value: 5000
```

`service-front` exposes a worker-pod which returns a 500 response when invoked.

When the envoy service is invoked with curl, the worker responds 500 immediately and I couldn't get the retry to work in any way.

I have tried following approaches,

1. Setting the [retry_policy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/route/v3/route_components.proto#config-route-v3-retrypolicy) within [route](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/route/v3/route_components.proto#config-route-v3-routeaction) as specified in the above yaml
2. Setting the retry_policy within [virtual_host](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/route/v3/route_components.proto#config-route-v3-virtualhost)
3. Sending [x-envoy-retry-on](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/router_filter#x-envoy-retry-on) header to the request

None of the above makes the envoy to retry the request. I have enabled debug logs in the envoy but its not printing anything related.

Comment: Can you provide the documentation which you are following and also in your  yaml configuration the backend response interval is set to 0.25 seconds which is too low can you modify it to 5 sec or 10 sec and check whether the retry is working fine.

Comment: If you are trying to test whether retry function is working or not instead of configuring different values in envoy you can keep the correct configuration and downscale your backend service as the initial health check itself will fail with mismatched config and it might be the issue.

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni thank you for the response. I followed the official docs at https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/route/v3/route_components.proto#config-route-v3-retrypolicy and some examples at https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/http/http_routing. The config I posted above is put together using those docs. Also I am using the latest envoy image (envoyproxy/envoy:v1.29-latest)

Comment: I tried increasing the connect_timeout as you mentioned but its still not retrying. Also pls note my backend responds immediately, therefore 0.25s does not matter really.

Comment: And yes I am trying to test retry function, but I did not come across any recent concrete example. I had to put together this using whats available.
My backend responds with a dummy 500 response as expected, what is not working is the retrying.